# Broadcast from phone camera to RTMP Nigix Server

Tags: java, android, ionic-framework, camera, streaming

I had managed to start broadcasting to RTMP from OBS software.

For RTMP with Ngix, I used [this tutorial](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-a-video-streaming-server-using-nginx-rtmp-on-ubuntu-20-04). For PlayBack in android I used https://github.com/josemmo/libvlc-android

To stream to RTMP I used OBS software https://obsproject.com

Everything works well so far.

My question is can I broadcast from my android phone without using OBS software aka I want to use my phone camera to broadcast directly to RTMP server.

https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.dev47apps.droidcam&hl=en&gl=US

Similar function like Droidcam

Prefer ionic-react, but if no choice, i could try native android with java.

Update: I found this Android Library https://github.com/pedroSG94/rtmp-rtsp-stream-client-java

And did manage to record from camera but still missing on how to add key.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did manage with this library

https://github.com/begeekmyfriend/yasea

It is quite easy.